# My 4x4 Graph in Python using matplotlib,numpy and datasets is not working like I want it to do

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, dataset

So I got this homework problem where we need to make a graph with dataset named iris.

The Graph should look exactly like the following
[image: GraphShouldLookLike]

But mine doesn't come out like this and I have tried everything that I can think of.

I got it to work but it doesn't look the same so I started playing around and got to a point where I ended with the errors below this image
[image: ThisIsMyResult]

```
ended with the following errors
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last) in 
     28 ax2.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 2], c=cols)
     29 ax2.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 3], c=cols)
---> 30 ax2.scatter(data[:, 1], data[:, 4], c=cols)
     31 ax2.scatter(data[:, 1], data[:, 5], c=cols)
     32 ax2.scatter(data[:, 1], data[:, 6], c=cols)

IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4
```

Any Assistance would be appreciated...

Thanks in Advance

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
    import numpy as np

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = plt.subplot(4, 3, 1)
    ax2 = plt.subplot(4, 3, 2)
    ax3 = plt.subplot(4, 3, 3)
    ax4 = plt.subplot(4, 3, 4)
    ax5 = plt.subplot(4, 3, 5)
    ax6 = plt.subplot(4, 3, 6)
    ax7 = plt.subplot(4, 3, 7)
    ax8 = plt.subplot(4, 3, 8)
    ax9 = plt.subplot(4, 3, 9)
    ax10 = plt.subplot(4, 3, 10)
    ax11 = plt.subplot(4, 3, 11)
    ax12 = plt.subplot(4, 3, 12)

    iris = load_iris()
    data = np.array(iris['data'])
    targets = np.array(iris['target'])

    cd = {0: 'r', 1: 'b', 2: 'g'}
    cols = np.array([cd[target] for target in targets])

    ax1.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], c=cols)
    ax2.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 2], c=cols)
    ax2.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 3], c=cols)
    ax2.scatter(data[:, 1], data[:, 4], c=cols)
    ax2.scatter(data[:, 1], data[:, 5], c=cols)
    ax2.scatter(data[:, 1], data[:, 6], c=cols)
    ax2.scatter(data[:, 2], data[:, 7], c=cols)
    ax2.scatter(data[:, 2], data[:, 8], c=cols)
    ax2.scatter(data[:, 2], data[:, 9], c=cols)
    ax2.scatter(data[:, 3], data[:, 10], c=cols)
    ax2.scatter(data[:, 3], data[:, 11], c=cols)
    ax2.scatter(data[:, 3], data[:, 12], c=cols)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to access an index which does not exist. The shape of your `data` is `(150, 4)`. You can do this using

```
print (data.shape)
# (150, 4)
```

Since the indexing starts from 0 in python, this means the second index of the `data` can be 0, 1, 2 and 3. You are however using the index 4 when you do

```
ax2.scatter(data[:, 1], data[:, 4], c=cols)
```

This is where you get the error. The same error will show up when you do `data[:, 5], data[:, 6], data[:, 7], data[:, 8]` and so on. You need to first make sure what data you want to show. Then choose the indices properly.

Comment: Haha! I saw my Mistake @Sheldore ax2.scatter(data[:, 1], data[:, 4], c=cols) ax2 was everywhere must of happened during one of my keyboard naps. But the indices show now in a straight line, would love it if I could get the indices correct :/

Comment: @Faziki : The problem is not that you have used `ax2` everywhere but that `data[:, 4]` is wrong just like `data[:, 5]`, `data[:, 6]`, `data[:, 7]` and so on... There is no 4, 5, 6, ... index. You need to figure out what data you want to plot.

Comment: @Faziki What is the relation between a dataframe of shape (150, 4) and 16 subplots?

Comment: only 12 subplots